# Double directory separators

Tags: windows-7, linux, windows, unix

I wanted to ask about double directory separators, I'm using windows 7 and as i checked there is not problem for example with this string `////\\\//\\\/\` to be used as a directory separator, The problem is with other systems it will be harder to check.

**My question is**

Do all systems that supports (**/  \  :**) as directory separators also supports double directory separator.

For example do **Mac OS** supports `:::::::` ?

or

Do Unix-like systems supports `////////`

**Edit:**

Let me see if i got you right about the internal directory separator:

**When i say internal i mean ('/someFolder/anotherFolder') the second slash.**

Mac/Windows/Unix-like supports **\ and /** as a directory separator.

**or**

Windows uses **/ and \** and Unix-like/Mac uses **only /**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends :)

There are some special cases for certain doubles.

In Windows, \\ at the beginning starts a flag for certain things. The UNC path \\volumename\path is a CIFS/SMB path for instance. In Win95/98 days, certain device drivers were \\Driver\.\

UNIX/POSIX allows // at the beginning to mean something special, but doesn't require it. All other // instances in the path are collapsed.  On most systems an initial // doesn't mean anything but is just collapsed to /. Cygwin, which is POSIX on Windows, uses initial // to mean the start of a UNC path.

```
Do Unix-like systems support ////////
```

Yes. Most UNIX systems would just collapse this to `/`. Cygwin (which is unix-like) should collapse this to / also, since //[nullVolume]/ doesn't make sense.

MacOS, hmm, that's hard. Why? Because the : isn't special anymore. Steve Jobs pretty much got rid of what was the old "Classic" filesystem on System 2-9. That environemnt doesn't ship anymore under MacOS X and it's truly UNIX filesystems, with extra metadata.  Even macs that could support "Classic" in the microkernel are few and far between now. You probably wouldn't bump into it unless you were looking for it. MacOS X does all the same UNIX things with ////// that everyone else does.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Rich, Can you please check my question edit.

Comment: @uBlankText  Mac and Other UNIX systems only support '/'. There are only two special characters, '\0' NULL (end the pathname), and '/', everything else goes.  Windows can use either '\', or '/' (allowed since DOS days for compatibility)